# Open an url video in a VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am trying to open a video in a videoView using an url.

Here are the code i use:

```
public void playVideo(){
String path= "http://s3.amazonaws.com/yendis_development/uploads/container/content/4fd79353c83b7260e6000003/3.mpg";
String path1="http://commonsware.com/misc/test2.3gp";

Uri uri=Uri.parse(path);
VideoView video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_view);
video.setVideoURI(uri);
video.start();
}
```

When i use "path1", my VideoView get the video and play it fine. 
but when i use "path", i don't get the video and i got a dialog saying "Sorry, this video cannot be played".

Why the webview worked for the path1 and not for path? You can open path and path1 in the navigator so you can see videos' test.

When path, In my logcat, i got this message (error):

```
08-11 17:08:47.411: E/MediaPlayer(10064): error (1, -2147483648)
08-11 17:08:47.411: E/MediaPlayer(10064): Error (1,-2147483648)
08-11 17:08:47.411: D/VideoView(10064): Error: 1,-2147483648
```

Thanks

Comment: i copy your url any played on my browser its not playing dua to HD video so it may b the reason so test with light weighted video your path1 url played fine.

Comment: Check this link out at : http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2011/03/simple-example-using-videoview-to-play.html .. Check the video link they have given and try to play the video

Comment: i tested, i guess it is because an mpg file. i think a videoView doesn't support mpg videos file.